# Media player current position not working good

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my seekbar and whe i don mp.getCurrentPosition(); onProgressChanged the seconds are going by 2 sometimes by 3 .... 0:01 ,0:03 , 0:05, 0:08 im not understanding whyy ??
im trying but nothing

-this is my seekbar

```
 seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            mp.getCurrentPosition();

            updateProgressBar();


        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            duration.setText(utils.milliSecondsToTime(mp.getCurrentPosition()));
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            updateProgressBar();


        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
            int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);
            mp.seekTo(currentPosition);
            updateProgressBar();


        }
    });
}
```

- this is my converter

```
    public String milliSecondsToTime(long milliseconds) {
        String finalTimerString = "";
        String secondString = "";

        // Convert total  duration into time
        int hours = (int) (milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        int minutes = (int) (milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
        int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);
        // Add hours if there
        if (hours > 0) {
            finalTimerString = hours + ":";

        }
        // Preparing 0 to seconds if it is digit
        if (seconds < 10) {
            secondString = "0" + seconds;
        } else {
            secondString = "" + seconds;
        }
        finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondString;
        // return timer string
        return finalTimerString;
    }
```